# Array.prototype.reduce implementation

Tags: javascript

I am learning how Array.reduce works in JS. In the following code I am trying to imitate the behavior of Array.prototype.reduce. How can I define Array.prototype.myReduce so that it doesn't require the array parameter just as Array.prototype.reduce.

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = (array, callback, initialVal) => {
    for (let el of array) {
      initialVal = callback(el, initialVal);
    }
    return initialVal;
};

console.log([].myReduce([1, 2, 3], (a, b) => a + b, 10));
```

Comment: Use `this` instead.

Comment: ^^ And use a traditional function, not an arrow function. **And** whenever modifying built-in prototypes (which is best avoided), at minimum make your modifications non-enumerable via `defineProperty`. See the answers to the linked question for details.

Comment: If you want to make it function identically, you'll also want to 1: handle (i.e. skip) empty slots in a sparse array, and 2: call the callback with 4 arguments, i.e. `(accumulator, currentValue, index, array)`, not `(currentValue, accumulator)`